# C#: How do I repaint my form when it's not focused?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to repaint/invalidate/refresh my form so that it updates seamlessly when it's not focused. How can I achieve this? Right now it will only update itself when I give it focus or move my mouse over it etc.

Edit: I tried using a timer that would call this.Invalidate(); every 25millisecond

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe `Invalidate();` is what you're looking for, it forces the particular control (Whether it be a form or menu etc.) to redraw itself on the next update.

I've never used it myself so i'm curious if it actually works.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/598t492a.aspx

Comment: Already tried it as mentioned above. It will only repaint the form when the form is focused.

Comment: Have you tried using it on the Deactivated event handler for the form?

Comment: Ah, yeah I had! My timer was set to be turned off. Silly me. Thanks for the tip!