# How do I change a property of a control several times during a loop in C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
int i;
while(true)
{
    label1.Text = i.ToString();
    i++;
    Thread.Sleep(500);
}
```

(in reality I'm trying to do something more complex and that makes more sense but this is a simple example of my problem)
I'm expecting that the text of the lable changes each 1/2 seconds..but it is getting stuck.

Thanks you

Comment: Can you provide more info; as to where it's getting stuck OR piece of code?

Comment: use breakpoints and see where it is getting stuck...f10 and f11 should fix your problem

Comment: Nononononononononono don't sleep the UI thread!

Comment: @alex , can you tell us your requirements, we can suggest you some beter design or solution.

Comment: Add label1.Update().  This doesn't prevent the UI from going catatonic and the "Not Responding" ghost window from appearing.  Use a Timer or a BackgroundWorker.

Answer (score 5):

You can't make the GUI-Thread sleep (Because than the GUI wont respond) (And I'm saying that even though I like sleeping * **A LOT** *).

Consider one of the following alternatives:

- Running this code on a separate thread
- Creating a timer with 500 as an interval
- Some sort of binding

Comment: yep thats true , very bad idea to sleep on GUI thread , it will definetly stuck

Answer (score 3):

Sleeping the UI thread makes things *worse*, as it can't respond to "paint" events until it has finished your method.

The most appropriate option here is a timer, doing a bit of work on each tick.

A lazy and deeply flawed approach is to add Application.DoEvents() - I only mention this to allow me to say DON'T DO THIS!!!

Answer (score 0):

Use a background thread or a timer, otherwise you will block the UI:

```
Thread t = new Thread( () =>
{
    int i = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        label1.Invoke( new Action(() => { label1.Text = i.ToString();}));
        i++;
        Thread.Sleep(500);
    };   
});
t.IsBackground = true;
t.Start();
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you have it now, your code is running on the same thread as the GUI. After you set the new label text you immediately sleep which prevents any code responsible for actually updating the screen from running. You can put `Application.DoEvents()` before your sleep call to force it to process any messages but that's not a real solution.

What you need to do is put your time-consuming code on a different thread. The .NET Timer class is made for something simple like this. You could also make your own separate thread containing your loop code. Just make sure you only access the label from the same thread it was created on. You can accomplish that by passing a delegate to `label1.Invoke` that does the actual text updating.

Comment: It would be best to not even mention `Application.DoEvents()` as a possible solution.

Answer (score -1):

There is no break condition on your loop

maybe you're trying to do, see that Update is called to repaint the label.

```
int i; 
for (i=0; i!=10; i++){ 
        label1.Text = i.ToString();
        label1.Update();
        Thread.Sleep(500); 
}
```

Comment: @james , he just posted sample code, he doesn't mean while true which is infinte loop, the problem is sleep on main GUI thread

Answer (score -1):

You will never get out of the while loop, thus the stuck part.  Also, if this is a WinForm, you need to repaint/invalidate/refresh your UI to see anything update.  More info on that here:  [C#: How do I repaint my form when it's not focused?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068176/c-how-do-i-repaint-my-form-when-its-not-focused)